# Is there a pdf generation library which helps in generating highly formatted reports?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pie-chart

I have some data in csv format which needs to be converted to tables, pie chart and text boxes in a word document.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Are you doing it manually or with a program?  You'll need to describe more before anyone can help you.